# How to get the HTTP response text from a HttpRequest.postFormData's catchError's _XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent?

Tags: dart, dart-html

Given the following pseudo code:

```dart
import "dart:html";

HttpRequest.postFormData(url, data).then((HttpRequest request) {

    ...

}).catchError((error) {

    // How do I get the response text from here?

});
```

If the web server replies with a `400 BAD REQUEST` then the `catchError` will be invoked. However, the error parameter is of the type `_XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent` which apparently doesn't exist in Dart's library.

So, how do I get the response text from the `400 BAD REQUEST` response that was sent from the web server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the target in your error object is actually your HttpRequest.

You may find this link helpful: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/forms/#handling-post-requests

You could do something like:

```dart
import "dart:html";

HttpRequest.postFormData(url, data).then((HttpRequest request) {
    request.onReadyStateChange.listen((response) => /* do sth with response */);
}).catchError((error) {
    print(error.target.responseText); // Current target should be you HttpRequest
});
```

Comment: I am uncertain if this is correct, as I am not even getting into the 'then' function. Besides, i think your example is broken, since request is unknown in onData(_).

Comment: I have been testing this, and it seems like most 2XX is okay, and most 4XX and 5XX calls the 'catchError'.

Comment: @corgrath It seems like you're right. I've tested this now as well. You need to pass in request to the onData - that was a cp fail. Try using error.currentTarget.responseText

Comment: Yea, wow, great. Where did you learn about this error.currentTarget.responseText??

Comment: @corgrath run the program, place a breakpoint and inspect the object... see what is in it... :)

Comment: OBS! I have to warn that it seems like error.currentTarget does not work anymore, but has to be error.current; http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17357 (Please upvote this!)

Comment: I updated the answer to use `target` instead of `currentTarget`

Comment: This also works for response type arraybuffer (error.target.response)

Comment: how do we see what is in the object without placing a breakpoint?